# What does it mean `bWatchSubtree` parameter of the `FindFirstChangeNotification` function?

Tags: api, delphi, directory, monitoring

I want to monitor a folder with [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationw) and I do not understand the meaning of `bWatchSubtree` parameter. What does it means "subtree"? It refers to folders that are children of the monitored folder, or the parent folders from the monitored folder to the drive letter?

Microsoft says:

> If this parameter is TRUE, the function monitors the directory tree
> rooted at the specified directory; if it is FALSE, it monitors only
> the specified directory.

Lets say we have the following path: D:\Software\Programming\Delphi\RADStudio

If I monitor "D:\Software\Programming" and that parameter is `True`, for what folders I will get notifications besides "Programming"? (Software) or (Delphi and RADStudio)?

I did some tests and I don't get any notifications when I change something in "Delphi or RADStudio" folders. But I get notified if I delete "Software" folder. If I want to change its name, the system won't let me, which is very frustrating. I want to be able to do any operations with file and folders when I monitor a folder. If I change the name of one of the parent folders it will be nice to notify me and stop watching that folder...

Comment: The "subtree rooted at a folder" surely means this folder and all subdirectories at any level below it. It's a [subtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) in the mathematical sense.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand In my case, I will get notifications for "Delphi and RADStudio" folders ? Becuse I don't get any...

Comment: "Programming", "Delphi", and "RADStudio", yes. And any other descendants of the root dir. I am a bit myopic and therefore I am not able to see the code on your screen from my Linköping apartment, so I cannot really say what the problem is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A file system is a mathematical [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)). A *subtree rooted at a directory* hence means the subtree consisting of that directory and all its descendants, that is, all its subdirectories at any level.

For example,

```
                          C:\
                           │
           ┌───────────────┴──────────────┐
        Letters                        Pictures
           │                              │
  ┌────────┴────────┐            ┌────────┴────────┐
Family             Work         Cats              Dogs
                                                   │
                                          ┌────────┴────────┐
                                        Small              Large
```

The subtree rooted at `Pictures` consists of `Pictures`, `Cats`, `Dogs`, `Small`, and `Large`, while the subtree rooted at `Dogs` consists of `Dogs`, `Small`, and `Large`.

I just tried it, and the  [`FindFirstChangeNotification`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstchangenotificationw) function and its `bWatchSubtree` parameter does indeed work as expected according to this interpretation.

I used the following very quick and dirty code to test this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  h: THandle;
begin
  h := FindFirstChangeNotification('C:\Pictures', True, FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME);
  if h = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE then
    RaiseLastOSError;
  TThread.CreateAnonymousThread(
    procedure
    begin
      while True do
        if WaitForSingleObject(h, INFINITE) = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
        begin
          OutputDebugString('Yes!');
          FindNextChangeNotification(h);
        end;
    end
  ).Start
end;
```

If I rename any picture, I do get a `Yes!` message. It doesn't matter if it's a dog or a cat picture, or if the dog is small or large. With `bWatchSubtree = False`, I am only notified when files *in the `Pictures` folder* are renamed. Renaming a dog or a cat picture isn't detected.

Comment: Indeed. There was a problem with my code... Thanks !

Comment: @MarusNebunu: No problem!